# Set constraints to arc UIBezierPath done programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, calayer

I am developing a custom circular progress bar, but I don't know to center it to the same center of the progress label for all devices. As it is a `CAShapeLayer`, I can't use `SnapKit` neither add constraints manually, at least I couldn't do it by code, it doesn't have the constraint property.

This is the view on iPhone 8 if my storyboard is set to iPhone 8:
[image]

This is the view on iPhone X using the same storyboard settings: 
[image]

My `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var percentageLoadedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uiView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createCircleProgressBar()
    }

    //MARK: Init track
    func createCircleProgressBar() {
        let center = percentageLoadedLabel.center

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 3*CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)

        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10

        uiView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    }
}
```

It has some offset on other devices as well, but when I change the storyboard to iPhone X, it works fine, only for this device, it looks like the line `let center = percentageLoadedLabel.center` gets the center designed on the storyboard, before it is updated by the constraints.

I tried to add a `UIView` on the storyboard and add both elements (`UILabel` and `CAShapeLayer`) inside to get the center property, but it doesn't work.

I've being struggling for a couple of days with this, I also tried to do it using `@IBDesignable`, but I face the same problem. I appreciate if someone could help me with this!

Comment: Could you share your complete demo project ?

Comment: The whole xcode project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj3jsy0vxxuug8u/Constraint.zip?dl=0 . Thanks for the help @dip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right when you say:

> it looks like the line let center = percentageLoadedLabel.center gets the center designed on the storyboard, before it is updated by the constraints.

In `viewDidLoad` you don't know the correct size of the view yet, and therefore you cannot rely on `center`, `bounds` `frame` and so on yet.

However, there is the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)).

As it says:

> Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.

So, if I move your call to `createCircleProgressBar()` to `viewDidLayoutSubview()` like so:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    createCircleProgressBar()
}
```

I see this on an iPhone 8 plus

[image: iPhone 8 plus]

And this on an iPhone X

[image: iPhone X]

And it looks nice on an iPhone 8 as well :)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks @pbodsk! I works fine now! It was a conceptual mistake, thanks again for the explanation  :)

Comment: You're welcome @RenanSilveira, glad you got it working. And don't worry, I've made that mistake many times myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `createCircleProgressBar()` method call to `ViewDidAppear`
The problem is that view does not completely get laid out in `viewDidLoad()`

You better move this implementation to custom view, and set the `uiView` class to your custom view class in the storyboard .

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

is the best place to get the center of the view.